# Интеграция Tilda и Django

Tags: python-3.x, django

хочу интегрировать Тильду и ДЖанго, нужно Лендинги которые созданы на Тильде публиковать через Джанго. как лонгриды, без изменения, создал модель для материалов С Тильды в Джанго

```
class TildaPage(models.Model):
    tilda_project_id = models.IntegerField()
    tilda_page_id = models.IntegerField()
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

представление:

```
def sync_tilda_pages(request):
    # Получите данные с Tilda
    tilda_pages = get_tilda_pages()

    # Если данные не получены, верните JsonResponse с сообщением об ошибке
    if tilda_pages is None:
        return JsonResponse({'status': 'error', 'message': 'Failed to fetch Tilda pages'})

    # Сохраните или обновите данные в вашей базе данных
    for page in tilda_pages:
        tilda_page, created = TildaPage.objects.update_or_create(
            tilda_id=page['id'],
            defaults={'title': page['title'], 'content': page['html']}
        )

    # Получите все страницы из вашей базы данных
    all_pages = TildaPage.objects.all()

    return render(request, 'news/longridy.html', {'pages': all_pages})
```

настроил урл для проверки синхронизации

```
    path('sync-tilda-pages/', sync_tilda_pages, name='sync_tilda_pages'),
```

при попытки синхронизации получаю ошибку

```
ConnectionError at /sync-tilda-pages/
HTTPSConnectionPool(host='api.tildacdn.com', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /v1/pages/list/?publickey=9i6f6g2g8qdqtw9bw3e5&secretkey=ae5ea70f3c9438f75a56 (Caused by NameResolutionError("<urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection object at 0x00000291435FDA90>: Failed to resolve 'api.tildacdn.com' ([Errno 11001] getaddrinfo failed)"))
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/sync-tilda-pages/
Django Version: 3.2
Exception Type: ConnectionError
Exception Value:    
HTTPSConnectionPool(host='api.tildacdn.com', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /v1/pages/list/?publickey=9i6f6g2g8qdqt43543fasf&secretkey=ae5ea704у64dfdfsr (Caused by NameResolutionError("<urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection object at 0x00000291435FDA90>: Failed to resolve 'api.tildacdn.com' ([Errno 11001] getaddrinfo failed)"))
Exception Location: E:\backup_09-12-2022\Документы\Доки_мега\Python_learn\django\014\venv\Lib\site-packages\requests\adapters.py, line 519, in send
Python Executable:  E:\backup_09-12-2022\Документы\Доки_мега\Python_learn\django\014\venv\Scripts\python.exe
Python Version: 3.11.3
Python Path:    
['E:\\backup_09-12-2022\\Документы\\Доки_мега\\Python_learn\\django\\014\\tmedia',
 'C:\\Program Files\\Python311\\python311.zip',
 'C:\\Program Files\\Python311\\DLLs',
 'C:\\Program Files\\Python311\\Lib',
 'C:\\Program Files\\Python311',
 'E:\\backup_09-12-2022\\Документы\\Доки_мега\\Python_learn\\django\\014\\venv',
 'E:\\backup_09-12-2022\\Документы\\Доки_мега\\Python_learn\\django\\014\\venv\\Lib\\site-packages']
Server time:    Mon, 27 Nov 2023 16:34:39 +0600
```

видимо не в ту сторону капаю, поправьте что делать, чтобы правильно интегрировать тильду и джанго чтобы получить список материалов с тильды как на вордпрессе и публиковать их на джанго,

получил публичные ключи с тильды и их вставляю при запросе. запрос с джанги не работает при этих же ключах, с вордпресса работает.

есть еще другое представление

```
@csrf_exempt
def tilda_sync(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        data = request.POST
        tilda_page = TildaPage(
            tilda_id=data.get('id'),
            title=data.get('title'),
            content=data.get('html')
        )
        tilda_page.save()
        return JsonResponse({'status': 'success'})
    return JsonResponse({'status': 'error'})
```

его урл:

```
path('tilda-sync/', tilda_sync, name='tilda_sync'),
```

при открытии его тоже ошибка

```
{
    "status": "error"
}
```